# Python - not getting the Video URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to extract the video URL embedded in the page using BeautifulSoup and lxml parser. I searched a lot to get the right PYTHON code for this but no success yet after many days. My code so far is as below -

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://telly-loans.com/watchvideo.php?id=0kw7cgyat4p7'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = headers
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    response = session.get(soup.iframe['src'], headers={'Referer': url})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

    print re.search(r'http:\/\/"(.*?)"', soup.script.text).group(1)
```

I have very limited python experience and must be missing something here. Does anyone tried for similar pages and can help me to get this done.

PAGE URL - http://telly-loans.com/watchvideo.php?id=0kw7cgyat4p7

Part of the HTML with IFRAME

```
<td>
   <div id='div-gpt-ad-1466152083933-1' style='height:600px; width:160px;'>
     <script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1466152083933-     1'); });
     </script>
   </div><!-- END TAG --
</td>
<td>
   <IFRAME SRC="http://watchvideo2.us/embed-0kw7cgyat4p7-540x304.html" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=540 HEIGHT=304>   </IFRAME>
      </td>
```

Comment: Please include a sample bit of HTML that shows the same problem, rather than linking to an external webpage. If they decide to change how the site is coded and your code starts to work on it, this question becomes unintelligible.

Comment: Added section of the HTML with iframe

Comment: You are probably scrapping the wrong place. See `http://watchvideo2.us/embed-0kw7cgyat4p7-540x304.html`

Comment: @ppaulojr unless that's the actual URL he's trying to get.

Comment: Why does your regex `r'http:\/\/"(.*?)"'` contain double quotes `"`? You should use `r'http:\/\/(.*?)'`

Comment: @ppaulojr When I scrap the iFrame URL, I am getting some javascript <script type="text/javascript">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+c.toString(a)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('7("3l").3k({3j:[{g:"2://k.j.27.h/3i/,t,.3h/3g.3f"},{g:"2://k.j.27.h/t/v.3e",3d:"3c"}],3b:"2://k.j.27.h/i/3a/39/38.37",36:"35",34:"f%",33:"f%",32:"31",30:"16:9"....... and few HTML with no option get to any 'm3u8' or mp4 etc.